# Java Graphics not rendering SVG (SVG Salamander and BufferedImage)

Tags: java, svg, graphics, bufferedimage

I'm working on a sample app that shows a radiography and the user must be able to mark interest points by clicking on it (as well as placing teeth and drawing polylines).

The approach consists on having a SVG file associated to the image, which had a simple structure: each line defines a point, so when the image is opened, we place on a frame a combination of the original image and the SVG rendered to a BufferedImage, with the method drawGraphics from Graphics.

The frame has a mouseListener that adds a line to the SVG file with a dot on the pixel clicked. Then it re-renders the original image with the updated SVG on top. The thing is, this works fine when the image is first loaded, but it is not updated when clicked, it does not show any new points until the app is closed and then opened again (the SVG file is indeed updated, as seen on a text editor).

I've tried calling invalidate and repaint on the Image Viewer, but it does not work.

The dynamic is quite simple: the image file is loaded and then the related ones are rendered on top with the drawImages method. When all of them are done, the final result is placed in the frame. I'm using the SVG Salamander library for the rendering, as it was quite straightforward to do. Batik looked more complete but also more complicated.

```
public class Test {

    Graphics g;
    ImageViewer v;
    BufferedImage imagenbase;
    ArrayList<BufferedImage> images;
    String basename;

    int count = 0;

    SVGUniverse universe;
    SVGDiagram diagram = null;

    public Test() {
        v = new ImageViewer(1200, 1200, 1.0, this);
        universe = new SVGUniverse();
    }

    public void drawSVGdot(int x, int y) {
        File file = new File(basename + "extra.svg");
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                List<String> lines;
                Path path = file.toPath();
                lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                String extra = "    <circle cx=\"" + x + "\" cy=\"" + y + "\" r=\"1\" style=\"fill:red;stroke:red\"/>";
                lines.add(1, extra);
                Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

        } else {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
                int h = v.getHeight();
                int w = v.getWidth();
                sb.append("<svg width=\"" + w + "\" height=\"" + h + "\" style=\"fill:none;stroke-width:4\">");
                sb.append("\n");
                sb.append("    <circle cx=\"" + x + "\" cy=\"" + y + "\" r=\"1\" style=\"fill:red;stroke:red\"/>");
                sb.append("\n");
                sb.append("</svg>");
                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                    writer.append(sb);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                } finally {
                    if (writer != null)
                        try {
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        loadRelatedImages(basename);
    }

    public void loadImage(String uri, String uriless) {
        try {
            basename = uriless;
            imagenbase = ImageIO.read(new File(uri));
            g = imagenbase.getGraphics();
            v.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void loadRelatedImages(String uri) {
        BufferedImage[] imgs = new BufferedImage[5];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            File file = new File(uri + i + ".svg");
            if (file.exists())
                imgs[i - 1] = SVGtoImage(file);
        }
        File file = new File(uri + "extra.svg");
        if (file.exists())
            imgs[4] = SVGtoImage(file);

        BufferedImage imagenfinal = new BufferedImage(imagenbase.getWidth(), imagenbase.getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        g = imagenfinal.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(imagenbase, 0, 0, null);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            if (imgs[i] != null) {
                g.drawImage(imgs[i], 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
        v.setImage(imagenfinal);
        v.invalidate();
        v.repaint();
        v.setVisible(true);
    }

    public BufferedImage SVGtoImage(File f) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(v.getHeight(), v.getWidth(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        try {
            universe.loadSVG(f.toURI().toURL());
            URI xmlBase = f.toURI();
            diagram = universe.getDiagram(xmlBase);
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
            diagram.render(g);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (SVGException e) {
        }
        return bi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();

        String imagename = "7.jpg";
        String withoutext = imagename.substring(0, imagename.lastIndexOf('.'));

        t.loadImage(imagename, withoutext);
        t.loadRelatedImages(withoutext);

    }
}
```

I doubt the problem is on the Image Viewer code, as it is painfully simple, but if it's requested I can post it, I just don't want to make this longer.

Thanks in advance.
Antonio.

Comment: You ask why something don't work, but have a lot of empty catch blocks.. That's usually a good place to start. At the very list, add `e.printStackTrace()`. Also, you should create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, rather than just dumping the code you have (which we can't run). This will help others help you. :-)